# Lots of squiggly lines after updating to .net core 2.1 - 'may need to supply run time policy'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-core-2.1

Don't know why I did, but I updated to .Net Core 2.1 yesterday. Ever since I updated, I am seeing tons of squiggly lines **throughout my solution** in Visual Studio on mac (so annoying). Here's the warning message -

[image]

I think understand the source of the warning. Basically, I am referencing to a lot of 3rd party Nuget packages (Autofac, Serilog, etc.) and they are built with an older version of .Net Core. This is what the warning is trying to tell me I think. But my code works just fine, don't have any issues running it.

After researching a little bit, I think the error is [CS1701](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1701). It is also added [by default] to be ignored in the Compiler settings for all projects in my solution. This is why I am not seeing this warning reported when I build my project/solution. However, the squiggly's are still shown in the text editor in Visual Studio.

Visual Studio is kind enough to offer a solution to suppress these squiggly lines, by adding a pragma statement at the top of `.cs` file - `#pragma warning disable CS1701 // Assuming assembly reference matches identity`. But I am afraid I need to add this line to all `.cs` file in my solution (there are a lot).

Does anyone know any other better way to suppress these squiggly lines in the text editor, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goto Preferences->Text Editor -> Source Code Analysis -> Code Rules (tab) and change the line
    Rule Id="CS1701" Action="Warning" to
    Rule Id="CS1701" Action="Hidden" 
and press OK.

Wait a for a short while and the lines will disappear.

Comment: OMG, where were you all these days! It worked. Thank you!!

Comment: Had been looking for the solution to this annoying warning and compromised many times. This just worked, thanks! (After update settings, restart VS.)